# How do I separate each line of a .csv file into a string list>

Tags: c#, list, file, streamreader

I am new to c# and am attempting to read in a .csv file and put each line of text in to a separate list item so I can sort it later.

the .csv file is organised like so:

> 1;"final60";"United Kingdom";"2013-12-06 15:48:16";
>   2;"donnyr8";"Netherlands";"2013-12-06 15:54:32";
>   etc

This is my first attempt that doesn't work.It shows no errors in Visual studios 2010 but when I run the console program it displays the following Exception instead of the list.
`Exception of type 'System.OutOFMemoryException' was thrown.` Which is bizarre because the .csv file only contains a small list.

```
try
{
// load csv file
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file.csv"))
      {
       string line = file.ReadLine();
       List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
       // Do something with the lines from the file until the end of  
       // the file is reached. 
       while (line != null)
       {

          fileList.Add(line);

        }
        foreach (string fileListLine in fileList)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(fileListLine);
         }
       }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // Let the user know what went wrong.
   Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

So am I approaching this the correct way?

Comment: You should really use a CSV parsing tool rather than trying to roll your own.  There are enough edge cases to worry about that it's not worth trying to handle them all yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file you are loading isn't really big then you can use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines("file.csv").ToList();
```

As Servy pointed out in comment it would be better to use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

[File.ReadLines - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

If you need a `List<string>` then you can do:

```
List<string> list = File.ReadLines("file.csv").ToList();
```

Comment: You should use `ReadLines` rather than `ReadAllLines` here to avoid the overhead of constructing an array that isn't going to be needed.  And ideally the `ToList` could be removed to allow for streaming of the data, rather than eager loading of the whole file.

Comment: +1 for updating answer and taking care of contributions.

Answer (score 5):

You are not updating the `line` variable so the *line will be always different from  null* infinite  loop  which cause `OutOfMemoryException`

```
 try
    {
    // load csv file
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file.csv"))
          {
           string line = file.ReadLine();
           List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
           // Do something with the lines from the file until the end of  
           // the file is reached. 
           while (line != null)
           {

              fileList.Add(line);
               line = file.ReadLine();

            }
            foreach (string fileListLine in fileList)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(fileListLine);
             }
           }
    }
```

but  the correct  approaches will be

```
List<string> list = File.ReadLines("file.csv").ToList();
```

which is better than `File.ReadAllLines` for the following reason
**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):**

*`When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned;`*

Answer (score 1):

You should use `File.ReadAllLines()` and then parse the strings in the array.
For extremely large files this might not be feasible and you'll have to stream the single lines in and process them one by one.
But this is something you can only decide AFTER you have seen this quick approach failing miserably. Until then, stick to the quick and dirty.