# C# separating data within a line from a text file

Tags: c#, list, file, names

I have a data file

```
Name; LastName; EurosCents;
Name2; LastName2; EurosCents2;
```

(for example:

```
John; Smith; 4,20;
Josh; Peck; 6,50;
```

)

I need to read the data and then do some further work with it... Is there any way to read the lines and save them? As the only way to read from a text file is to read the entire line at once.

Comment: There are lots of ways! What is exactly not working?

Comment: You need to explain it a little more.

Comment: The only way ? No ! `File.ReadAllText();` vs  `File.ReadAllLines();` If if you read all the text at once, you can still split them by Line break !

Comment: Search for `String.Split`, or even better, some of the existing csv-parsers out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I separate each line of a .csv file into a string list>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484619/how-do-i-separate-each-line-of-a-csv-file-into-a-string-list)

Comment: The exact problem is that the way I do it - the entire line of "Name; LastName; EurosCents;" gets read as a single string

Comment: @BligenN Check the answer below. It shows how to split the line and get separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lst = File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath).Select(x => new
{  
   FirstName = x.Split(';')[0]
   LastName = x.Split(';')[1]
   Value = decimal.Parse(x.Split(';')[2])
}).ToList();
```

use

```
lst[7].FirstName = "xxx";
Console.WriteLine(lst[2].Value);
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The `File` API provide multiple options for reading files. Below is a possible way to proceed:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
{
    var splitted = line.Split(';');
    var name = splitted.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    var lastName = splitted.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    var cents = Decimal.Parse(splitted.ElementAtOrDefault(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple code to read whole file is as follows

```
    string[] test(string path)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        string[] str = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(';');
        sr.Close();
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Even better way - `StreamReader` implements `IDisposable`, so you can just use:
`using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) { /* cod here */ }`
Therefore stream closing will be managed on it's own ;)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing will be very easy if you are comfortable using LINQ.
Below line can get you the file in a hierarchical structure.

```
 var theselines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Test.txt").Select(l => l.Split(','));
```

You can see the result of above line by debugging.
Later you can have any logic to get the required data from each line without using foreach loop.

```
        var Data = theselines.Select(l => new
        {

            id = l.Where(t => t.Contains("01")).FirstOrDefault(),
            Price = l.Where(t => t.Contains(",")).FirstOrDefault(),
            Firstname= l[0],
            lastname = l[1]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing that *data itself* (both names and cents) can't contain `;` in order to get
items from the *comma separated values* you can just *split*:

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyData.csv")
  // .Skip(1) // <- in case you have caption to skip
  .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
  .Select(items => new {
       Name = items[0],
       LastName = items[1],
       EuroCents = decimal.Parse(items[2]) //TODO: check type and its format
    });
  //.ToArray(); // <- if you want to materialize as, say, an array
```

Then you can use it

```
 foreach (var item in data) {
   if (item.EuroCents > 10) {
     ...
   }
 }
```